# How to fix ".azure_rm plugin: a batched request failed with status code 403" error

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am attempting to configure an dynamic inventory for Azure.
I have created an Azure Credential with my Subscription ID, Tenant ID, Client ID, and my Client Secret.
I am using this ARM Credential in source configuration for the Inventory.
I am using ansible [core 2.14.4]
I am also using the latest version of the azcollection.

The results of attempting to sync the inventory results in the following:

```
[WARNING]: * Failed to parse /runner/inventory/azure_rm.yml with auto plugin: a batched request failed with status code 403, url /subscriptions/dev-null__/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines__
```

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot, or other tips would be very helpful.

I tried to install the latest version of Ansible and Azure CLI.
Also I double checked version of python3

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR:

**Execution Environments**

I personally encountered similar problems with the combination of Azure and Ansible.

**The short answer is that installing azure-cli from OS or pip3 will provide newer version from the one that ansible collection requires to work.**

At the time of writing there is an active github issue regarding this conflict https://github.com/ansible-collections/azure/issues/1138

**Answer A:**
Python Virtual Environment

I recommend to create a Python Virtual Environment and use it for you ansible runs. This method will keep libs and bins separated from OS and allow you to keep your current azure-cli installation up-to-date without the need to downgrade it just to use ansible.

1. Install python3-venv with your OS package manager (i.e. Ubuntu)

```bash
sudo apt-get install python3-venv
```

2. Create directory for the venv

```bash
mkdir ~/azure_venv
```

3. Create virtual environment inside that directory

```bash
python3 -m venv ~/azure_venv
```

4. Activate the virtual environment

```bash
cd ~/azure_venv

source bin/activate
```

5. Install ansible-core inside the virtual environment

```bash
pip3 install ansible-core==2.14.4
```

6. Download Azure Collection

```bash
ansible-galaxy collection install azure.azcollection
```

7. Install requirements inside the virtual environemnt (This will also install azure-cli-core in version that is required and compatible)

```bash
pip3 install -r ~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/azure/azcollection/requirements-azure.txt
```

8. **Run Ansible commands while virtual environment is active**

**Answer B:**
Ansible Execution Environment

There also exists a more sophisticated way to manage libraries and their requirements. Collections can conflict each other in terms of required python libraries so Ansible introduced "Execution Environments" that are based on containers instead of Python Virtual Environments.

The most convenient way to use them is to use AWX that is recommended for use with kubernetes so I am not going to recommend them here.

If you are interested in them you can read about them here:

https://github.com/ansible/awx - AWX

https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator - Deploying AWX

https://docs.ansible.com/automation-controller/latest/html/userguide/execution_environments.html - Execution Environments

https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ - Using Execution Environments